# clojure equality when comparing pseudo class instances

Tags: clojure

I have this clojure code from the book Functional Programming for the objet-oriented programmer:

```
(def point {:x 1, :y 2, :__class_symbol__ 'Point})

(def Point
     (fn [x y]
       {:x x,
        :y y
        :__class_symbol__ 'Point}))

(def x :x)
(def y :y)
(def class-of :__class_symbol__)

(def shift
     (fn [this xinc yinc]
       (Point (+ (x this) xinc)
              (+ (y this) yinc))))


(defn add [left right]
  (shift left (x right) (y right)))


(def Triangle
     (fn [point1 point2 point3]
       {:point1 point1, :point2 point2, :point3 point3
        :__class_symbol__ 'Triangle}))


(def right-triangle (Triangle (Point 0 0)
                              (Point 0 1)
                              (Point 1 0)))

(def equal-right-triangle (Triangle (Point 0 0)
                                    (Point 0 1)
                                    (Point 1 0)))

(def different-triangle (Triangle (Point 0 0)
                                  (Point 0 10)
                                  (Point 10 0)))

(defn equal-triangles? [& args]
  (apply = args))

(defn make [klass & args]
  (apply klass args))
```

I have created this function to check equality of the Triangle pseudo class:

```
(defn equal-triangles? [& args]
  (apply = args))
```

It is obvious why this expression is true

```
(= right-triangle right-triangle)
```

It is also obvious why this expression is not true

```
(equal-triangles? right-triangle different-triangle)
```

What is not obvious is why this expression is true:

```
(= right-triangle equal-right-triangle)
```

They both have the Point values but I would have thought they would be different because I am probably still thinking in terms of instances.

Can anyone shed any light on why the last expression is true?

Comment: you already have a good answer, but I think a missing piece of the puzzle here is the fact that with immutability, identity is less important than structural equality. If a thing will not be altered, there is no reason to track identity separate from value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
user=> (= right-triangle equal-right-triangle)
true
user=> (identical? right-triangle equal-right-triangle)
false
```

---

```
user=> (doc =)
-------------------------
... Clojure's immutable data structures define equals() (and thus =) 
as a value, not an identity, comparison.

user=> (doc identical?)
-------------------------
...Tests if 2 arguments are the same object
```